# Error while using readstream from delta on azure data lake gen 2

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

I get the below error while reading data from delta lake. The detailed log on azure shows its failing to read .tmp file from the _delta_log folder. I have tried adding trigger with 2 to 5 seconds but still face this issue.

Caused by: Operation failed: "The specified path does not exist.", 404, GET, https://xxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/xxxxcontainer?upn=false&resource=filesystem&maxResults=500&directory=LandingHome/_delta_log&timeout=90&recursive=false, PathNotFound, "The specified path does not exist. RequestId:d2b580d6-201f-0087-4216-5df359000000 Time:2022-05-01T04:44:55.4973721Z"
[image]

```
import io.delta.tables._
val hadoopConf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
import org.apache.spark.sql._
hadoopConf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.xx.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
hadoopConf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.xx.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider");
hadoopConf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.xx.dfs.core.windows.net", "sdfdfsdfdss");
hadoopConf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.xx.dfs.core.windows.net", "sdfdsfd");
hadoopConf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.xx.dfs.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/sdfdfsd/oauth2/token");
hadoopConf.set("fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization", "true");
hadoopConf.set("fs.abfs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem");


df = SparkBean.getSparkSession().readStream().format("delta").options(sparkProps).load(deltaLakeEventPath).where(condition)
df.writeStream().format("CustomSinkHandler").options(streamProps).start();
```

Comment: please provide configuration that you're using to connect to ADLS

Comment: I have updated my query with the conf

Answer (score 0):

Per [Delta documentation](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-storage.html#configuration-adls-gen2), you need to use `spark.conf` instead of setting these properties in Hadoop configuration (with them, it works just fine):

```py
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net",  "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<application-id>")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net","<password>")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token")
```

Don't forget to attach packages `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure-datalake` & `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure`.